# use SWR data in useState Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swr

```
  const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://some.com/api",
    fetcher,
  );
```

is there any way to add data in a useState hook like this

```
  const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/5",
    fetcher,
  );

const [memes,setMemes]=useState(data);
```

cause I want to concat the data at some point for inifnite scrolling

Comment: Side note: Your `fetcher` function is falling prey to a footgun in the `fetch` API [I describe here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). Before calling `json`, you probably want to check whether the HTTP  request was successful (`fetch` doesn't reject on HTTP errors, only network errors). So: ```const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((r) => { if (!r.ok) { throw new Error(`HTTP error ${r.status}`); } return r.json(); });```

Comment: FWIW, `useSWR` doesn't immediately seem to make sense with something like `https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/5` that always provides a new set of responses when you send it a request.

Comment: You can but only when your component mounts, because you need to wait for the api response in useSWR(), add the data as dependency so whenever it changes, it'll rerender.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what if I want to contact the data every new request

Comment: @JatinHemnani - What does "contact the data every new request" mean?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry I meant Concat(append the data)

Answer (score 5):

The fastest solution to transfer data from one variable to another is to use an `useEffect` hook. When `data` changes, update `memes`.

```
useEffect(() => { setMemes(data); }, [data])
```

##### Infinite scroling

A better solution would be to use SWR provided solutions for infinite scrolling. You have different options [documented here](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination#infinite-loading).

##### Plain fetch

In this case, you can also consider using directly the fetch function and appending data to the memes list directly:

```
const [ memes, setMemes ] = useState([]);

async function fetchAnotherPage() {
    const data = (await fetch('https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/5')).json();
    setMemes(value => [...value, ...data.memes]);
}

useEffect(() => fetchAnotherPage(), []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/5` always returns new data for each call, `useSWR` isn't a good fit for this and, moreover, the fact it retrieves from cache and gives that to your code and then revalidates and (possibly) calls your code to update, without telling you whether it's the first result or an update, makes it very hard to do what you're describing.

Instead, I'd just use `fetch` directly and not try to do the SWR thing; see comments:

```js
// Start with no memes
const [memes,setMemes] = useState([]);

// Use a ref to track an `AbortController` so we can:
// A) avoid overlapping fetches, and
// B) abort the current `fetch` operation (if any) on unmount
const fetchControllerRef = useRef(null);

// A function to fetch memes
const fetchMoreMemes = () => {
    if (!fetchControllerRef.current) {
        fetchControllerRef.current = new AbortController();
        fetch("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/5", {signal: fetchControllerRef.current.signal})
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(newMemes => {
            setMemes(memes => memes.concat(newMemes.memes));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // ...handle/report error...
        })
        .finally(() => {
            fetchControllerRef.current = null;
        });
    }
};

// Fetch the first batch of memes
useEffect(() => {
    fetchMoreMemes();
    return () => {
        // Cancel the current `fetch` (if any) when the component is unmounted
        fetchControllerRef.current?.abort();
    };
}, []);
```

When you want to fetch more memes, call `fetchMoreMemes`.

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect, useRef} = React;

const Example = () => {
    // Start with no memes
    const [memes,setMemes] = useState([]);

    // Use a ref to track an `AbortController` so we can:
    // A) avoid overlapping fetches, and
    // B) abort the current `fetch` operation (if any) on unmount
    const fetchControllerRef = useRef(null);

    // A function to fetch memes
    const fetchMoreMemes = () => {
        if (!fetchControllerRef.current) {
            fetchControllerRef.current = new AbortController();
            fetch("https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme/5", {signal: fetchControllerRef.current.signal})
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(newMemes => {
                // I'm filtering out NSFW ones here on SO
                setMemes(memes => memes.concat(newMemes.memes.filter(({nsfw}) => !nsfw)));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // ...handle/report error...
            })
            .finally(() => {
                fetchControllerRef.current = null;
            });
        }
    };

    // Fetch the first batch of memes
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchMoreMemes();
        return () => {
            // Cancel the current `fetch` (if any) when the component is unmounted
            fetchControllerRef.current && fetchControllerRef.current.abort();
        };
    }, []);
    
    const message = memes.length === 1 ? "1 meme:" : `${memes.length} memes:`;
    return <div>
        <div>{message} <input type="button" value="More" onClick={fetchMoreMemes}/></div>
        <ul>
            {/* `index` as key is ONLY valid because our array only grows */}
            {memes.map(({postLink}, index) => <li key={index}>{postLink}</li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>
};


ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```